C# ECDsa VerifyData = false with same Inputs
Overview
I'm trying to access Cisco Intersight API from C#. However I can't seem to build the Header signature. In the official Postman collection I grabbed the outputs of the Pre-Request function, including the signature and the string before it was signed. The project is a .NET 8 WinForms project.
Working example
Signature in Postman:
MEUCIEoSI3dEFJSRkcl4KUP6OWDMF/n9JOymDk8nRQmLY6ZoAiEA8JoHW5RMkAPreqFFKFTkgxB5TivVRuu4H5Iem9wH3SY=

Signature string to be signed in Postman (including line breaks, where the last line doesn't have one if that matters):
(request-target): get /api/v1/asset/DeviceContractInformations
date: Tue, 20 Aug 2024 03:08:58 GMT
digest: SHA-256=47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=
host: eu-central-1.intersight.com

For reference this is the Request Header in Postman (where the connection works):
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Signature keyId="668d65ea7564613305327c62/668d65ea7564613305327c66/66c3ce947564613005b05fc8",algorithm="hs2019",headers="(request-target) date digest host",signature="MEUCIEoSI3dEFJSRkcl4KUP6OWDMF/n9JOymDk8nRQmLY6ZoAiEA8JoHW5RMkAPreqFFKFTkgxB5TivVRuu4H5Iem9wH3SY="
Digest: SHA-256=47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=
Date: Tue, 20 Aug 2024 15:33:18 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.41.2
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 91664c05-6e49-475f-9c45-7aec71473361
Host: eu-central-1.intersight.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive

My code
In my C# code, I have a function that computes the signature, I was wondering if HashAlgorithmnName.SHA256 is the correct function, in the Header it specifies algorithm as "hs2019":
static string ComputeSignature(string stringToSign) 
{
    using(var fileStream = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\xxx\\PrivateKey.pem", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) 
    {
        using(var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream)) 
        {
           var pem = reader.ReadToEnd();
           Console.WriteLine($"Read PEM as: \n {pem}");

           try 
           {
               using var ecdsakey = ECDsa.Create();
               ecdsakey.ImportFromPem(pem);

               byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);

               var hashedBytes = ecdsakey.SignData(bytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
               bool isValid = ecdsakey.VerifyData(bytes, hashedBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);

               // testing
               string test = """
(request-target): get /api/v1/asset/DeviceContractInformations
date: Tue, 20 Aug 2024 03:08:58 GMT
digest: SHA-256=47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=
host: eu-central-1.intersight.com
""";
               byte[] testBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test);
               byte[] testhashedbytes = Convert.FromBase64String("MEUCIEoSI3dEFJSRkcl4KUP6OWDMF/n9JOymDk8nRQmLY6ZoAiEA8JoHW5RMkAPreqFFKFTkgxB5TivVRuu4H5Iem9wH3SY=");

               bool isValid2 = ecdsakey.VerifyData(testBytes, testhashedbytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);

               Console.WriteLine($"Computed hash valid: {isValid2}");
                        
               return Convert.ToBase64String(hashedBytes);
            } 
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {
               Console.WriteLine($"Couldn't load key from PEM: {ex}");
               throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}

Gist to my full code: https://gist.github.com/DursyArts/e04aeb3b6ef5d86f94c5f014ec56b894
Signing with my own key and data returns isValid = true, but the 2nd test with the postman data returns isValid2 = false.
I'm trying to figure out why I always get this when sending the request:
{
    "code": "AuthenticationFailure",
    "message": "Cannot perform the operation. Invalid API key. Verify the API keyID, status, account and retry.",
    "messageId": "iam_api_key_is_invalid",
    "traceId": "_f3xxxldrA7NSvvLZhqnIqu7A_exiZHxwCWBYxiJO1Eb5UhnQ=="
}

I suspect it's the signing function. Because the digest I calculate for the body matches that in Postman, but maybe someone has another idea of what the problem could be, why I can't verify the data and why my API requests fail to Intersight.

The signature is ASN.1/DER encoded, VerifyData() requires the P1363 format by default. Try this VerifyData(Byte[], Byte[], HashAlgorithmName, DSASignatureFormat) overload with DSASignatureFormat.IeeeP1363FixedFieldConcatenation.

hs2019 is mentioned in this internet draft which defines various signature algorithms (including ECDSA, P-256 and SHA-512). No idea if this is relevant to your case, but it can't hurt to try SHA-512 as well.

@Topaco Thanks, i now can sign data that roughly looks the same format as the ones the postman collection is making (like starting with 30...) https://gist.github.com/DursyArts/2c2bd350a60d91208df4caaf1284de3b (this is my function)
However, do you know where i can find more documentation on the ASN Reader and how to read the signature and get it back into the same form it was before (Ieee format)? Basically to verify the data again. Because im still getting ApiId or ApiKey invalid errors and i want to see if i did something wrong

I don't understand your intention: .NET supports both formats, by default P1363 (IeeeP1363FixedFieldConcatenation) and ASN.1/DER (Rfc3279DerSequence). So you only need to use Rfc3279DerSequence for the C# verification of the ASN.1/DER Postman/Intersight signature. If the verification then fails, there are additional problems besides the signature format. Conversely, if you want to create an ASN.1/DER signature, you only need to use Rfc3279DerSequence in the C# signing process.

Have you additionally tried HashAlgorithmName.SHA512 during verification? Incidentally, there is a bug in your home-made format conversion: each of the two WriteInteger() must be replaced by WriteIntegerUnsigned(). For an overview of the formats and as a guideline for their conversion, see also here. Can you provide a link to the Postman/Intersight signing process or a non-productive private test key including message and signature?

Hey again, I replaced the Format with the Rfc3279DerSequence and yes it works. I only saw the IeeeP1363 format, but now it makes sense. I also tried it with SHA-512 but im still denied, not sure if "Invalid API Key" means that my key is being read wrong, the api error messages arent really verbose. i uploaded my code, keys and postman collection script into this repo: https://github.com/DursyArts/C-IntersightAPITest/tree/main

i also tried looking through the example written in python at https://github.com/movinalot/intersight-rest-api/blob/master/intersight_auth.py but im not really good in python, i think both the postman code and the python code do roughly the same thing. i also removed the "EC" from BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY so that the key can be read by the ECDsa class.

im not sure if i can view the actual request being sent from postman, but when i compare the variables it looks almost identical (screenshot: http://x.kassiopeia.co/u/082fe34a-091a-415c-83fc-f1c3db070ae6.png ) The only thing that i notice is that the signature in my example has an = at the end and the postman one doesnt, not sure if thats relevant or just padding

Does the linked Python code definitely implement the logic correctly, i.e. should the C# code reproduce this logic? This code signs using RSA!

BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY marks an EC key in SEC1 format, BEGIN PRIVATE KEY one in PKCS#8 format. Simply removing the EC generally leads to an inconsistent key. It seems to me that the whole thing is just guesswork. You need a detailed description of the signing process, we need complete test data.

i found another repo https://github.com/CiscoDevNet/intersight-python-utils/blob/main/credentials.py and specifally the credentials.py file. These are newer examples from Cisco, i assumed it would be standard to remove the EC in the boundary because older examples in python, postman and the devnet course showed to remove it. Here they use:
elif re.search('BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY', api_key):
# API Key v3 format
signing_algorithm = intersight.signing.ALGORITHM_ECDSA_MODE_DETERMINISTIC_RFC6979
so i assume that this differs from what im doing in C#?

I added KeyCheck.py to the repository i created earlier, which seems to be a working example i created by taking pieces of various example code. Though this is based on the Intersight Python SDK which does most of the work. Maybe it helps to understand what is actually being done to make the signature

I cannot find ALGORITHM_ECDSA_MODE_DETERMINISTIC_RFC6979 in credentials.py.

In my opinion, your post is missing crucial information to answer the question, so I vote to close the question. For this question to be answerable, you kindly need to post the code used for signing or at least a detailed description of the signing process, including (non productive) test data: key, message, signature that can be successfully verified by the reference code.
